# Error in python when using .config() on a Label

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Ok, so I have a problem. I am trying to make a GUI Hex converter and i Keep getting the same error. I am not that experienced with Tkinter, so can someone help me? Here is the Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def getNum():
   hex1 = e1.get()
   dec1 = int(hex1, 16)
   ol.configure(text=dec1)



root = Tk()

introLabel = Label(root, text='Input Hex Code: ').pack()

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()
e1.focus_set()

inputButton = Button(root, text='Submit Hex Code', command=getNum).pack()

ol = Label(root, text='Hex Code will appear here.').pack()



root.mainloop()
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/The Lodges/Desktop/Python/test.py", line 6, in getNum
ol.configure(text=dec1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'
```

Answer (score 5):

The return value from `.pack()` is not the widget, but `None`.

Change code from this:

```
ol = Label(root, text='Hex Code will appear here.').pack()
```

To this:

```
ol = Label(root, text='Hex Code will appear here.')
ol.pack()
```

This will keep `ol` 'pointing' at the label.